# Landscape orientation flutter web app doesn't work for PWA on Android device

Tags: android, flutter, google-chrome, web, landscape

If I download my flutter web app as PWA with Chrome on my Android Device I cant change the rotation to landscape.

But it works with safari on my IOS device.

Does anyone no how to fix this issue?

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I needed to adjust the Flutter Web application's `manifest.json` to contain `"orientation": "landscape". This file is the PWA manifest.

See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Manifest/orientation for more options.

If you want to adjust it at runtime, see [ScreenOrientation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ScreenOrientation).